# how can countrymeters.info be true?

Tags: population

I'm wondering, how this site `countrymeters.info` manages to gather information?
They are displaying, as example "Net migration today" and information is updated real-time;

A few hours ago it was -7, now it is -10 .. [See](http://countrymeters.info/en/Latvia) for yourself. Do you know what tools are they using in managing so called "country monitoring"? Why should I trust that data. If there was known possible approach for monitoring such thing i would had reason enough to trust information this site provides.

I'm just guessing: Interpol provided data? If i just took a train and crossed a border, how would anyone know this. Very interesting.

Comment: While mapping this information is clearly relevant to GIS, statistical use of census data is less so.  An actual link to the site is an appropriate edit to this question.  The site itself is a poorly documented mess of advertising links, but it's clear that they're just applying a formula based on census information (birth rate, death rate, and net migration). The accuracy is clearly macro (trend-based), not based on tracking individuals.